# Event ID Tracker and CSV report on Multiple servers

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm trying to learn programming and Powershell scripting.

I'm working on a script to gather the list of servers (DCs in this case) that present an specific event id.

I want to add/change this code to get the list of servers that present the event ID and not only a txt with the server description like it does right now.

With this code I get a txt with the list of the servers and last event. But I also want to get in csv a list of the servers that have the event id active.

```
$DCsList = (Get-ADForest).Domains | %{Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_} | Select-Object HostName | Sort-Object Hostname

$result =  Foreach ($dcs in $DCsList){
try{
Get-WinEvent -computername $dcs -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=5774} -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | fl
}
catch{
}
write-output "$dcs doesn't have the event 5774 on the system log" 
}
$result | Out-File "D:\DNSRegEvents.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear on how you want your output formatted but assuming you want a CSV with one column being hostnames and the second column being if the eventid is present or not then is code will do that:

```
$DCsList = (Get-ADForest).Domains | %{Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $_} | Select-Object HostName | Sort-Object Hostname
$result =  Foreach ($dcs in $DCsList)
{
    If ((Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Logname='System';ID=5774} -MaxEvents 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).length -gt 0)
    {
        $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        Server = $dcs.HostName               
        Result = "Server has event"  
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{            
        Server = $dcs.HostName               
        Result = "Server does not have event"  
        }
    }
    $Object
}
$result | Export-Csv "D:\DNSRegEvents.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```